# Entity Framework - class not found

Tags: silverlight, class, frameworks, entity, auto-generate

I have a problem regarding a Silverlight application that uses ADO Entity Framework 4.0.
The application can't find one class auto-generated by entity framework, while the other classes auto-generated it finds.

Comment: Are you using WCF, WCF RIA services or other?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the error. The problem was in the compilation of the code.
The class had never been used before, so it was not autogenerated in the *. G.cs (autogenerated file).
To compile the class I used in the web part of the solution, and compiled it.
After filling me are found in the file *. G.cs part of Silverlight.